# Why is transparancy of GRASS rasters missing when imported into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, transparency-opacity

I have a raster map in QGIS imported from a GRASS mapset with the QGIS GRASS plugin. The problem is that I have null() cells in the GRASS map that appear "colored" in QGIS. How can I set the transparency?

I have tried in 'Proprieties' but it seems that it doesn't work. I would like to know a simple way to solve my problem.

Comment: When I add a GRASS raster into the QGIS map canvas, null cells are transparent. <shrug>

Comment: I tested on 3 machines. I can see in the layer's properties window - Transparency tab - the value -2e+09 (MAXINT) is set to 100% transparent.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. I noticed the layer's properties and I saw that there is a value of -1e+30 Anyway I doubt that the problem is the value. Have you set other things after you imported the grass map? because I still have a colored background instead of null cells transparency.

Comment: Can you kindly help me @Micha?

Comment: @mattrx86, could you clarify if you see the colored `null` cells when you first import the raster, or after you have assigned a colormap to it?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [Bug #4794](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4794), which is fixed in trunk and will graduate to the stable release in QGIS 2.0.